# How to properly render @font-face in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, font-face, webfonts

I am attempting to use @font-face for Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and IE.  For IE i am not even sure what to do but for the other browsers I want the @font-face part to work.

Here's what I have used:

```
  @font-face {
  font-family: "Handwriter";
  src: url("/folder/Font-Regular.otf");
  }
```

And then I also tried:

```
 @font-face {
 font-family: "Handwriter";
 src: url("http://www.domain.com/folder/Font-Regular.otf");
 }
```

Using either of these will render it properly in Chrome and Safari but not in Firefox.  The funny thing is that if I use Firebug and go to the CSS file and rewrite the name again then it renders it. In addition, the font file is on my server and I am rending this on the same domain. So not sure what is going wrong here.

Comment: you can also try the FontSquirrel font-face generator http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Comment: URLs to fonts need to be relative for them to work on Firefox, or you can configure your server to allow access to them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this (with your custom fonts). Remember the format is important:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'WebFont';
  src: url('myfont.woff') format('woff'),  /* Firefox 3.6+, IE9+, Chrome 6+, Safari 5.1+*/
       url('myfont.ttf') format('truetype');  /* Safari 3—5, Chrome4+, Firefox 3.5, Opera 10+ */
}
```

source: [css3please](http://css3please.com/)

Answer (score 3):

It's not an advertisement :D

I succefully use http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface generator :) If You have z ttf file the rest is a piece of cake :)