# @font-face still not working in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, font-face

I know that there is a known issue with @font-face and firefox. As far as I am aware i have followed all instructions I have found to fix it to no avail. Here is what I have:

- mysite.com includes a stylesheet on a different server, we will call it myresources.com.
- in the stylesheet, I am including my @font-face declaration, which is locally pathed as the stylesheet & fonts are on the same myresources.com domain.
- i can see in my response headers that the font is being downloaded by firefox with a 200OK status.
- i have an .htaccess file in the folder that contains only my fonts with the access-control-allow-origin "*" (yes i will lock this down later, but for now its a *)
- fonts are working in all other browsers, but still not firefox... what could I be doing wrong?

my font-face declaration:

```
@font-face{
  font-family: "myIcons";
  src: url("/images/fonts/convention-icons.eot");
  src: url("/images/fonts/convention-icons.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
       url("/images/fonts/convention-icons.woff") format("woff"), 
       url("/images/fonts/convention-icons.ttf") format("truetype"),    
       url("/images/fonts/convention-icons.svg#myIcons") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Also, the server the fonts & css are on is an IIS server... idk if that makes a difference or not

Comment: Can you show us your font-face code? Also- what's the extension of your file, .ttf or .woff?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has to do with the path.

On the `/page` page, FF will load fonts from `/page/fonts`, but not from `/fonts`.

[Source](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/956597)

[Helpful Link to How to add Fonts in FF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13508377/1669208)

Comment: i am using the path:
url("/images/fonts/my-icons.woff")
in my css file... i can see a 200OK returning from firefox... maybe i don't understand what you're saying?

Comment: I'm stumped. I'll try to look at this on Sunday when I have some more time.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i do not know what IIS thing was changed exactly (i do not have access) but the solution to the issue was found in this thread: [@font-face not displaying correctly in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744026/font-face-not-displaying-correctly-in-ie)

thank you for your help!